# Problem filtering for two conditions after joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

The code **should** return four entries, two from each condition, and it does return two for each if I take out the "OR" and the second condition and do them separately. If I try to do them like below, it returns the correct entries for the first condition but then switches all of the remaining entries in the table (23 in total) to have "Term2" in col3. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT t1.col3 AS "Title", t2.col2 AS "Title 2", t2.col3 AS "Title 3"
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 
AND t1.col3 = "Term1" OR t2.col3 = "Term2";
```

Comment: Not 100% possible to answer without more details, but it seems you missed to add parentheses. You should avoid such a where clause by using JOIN instead.

Comment: Where should I add the parentheses?

Comment: You can use IN  `.. AND t1.col3 IN ("Term1" ,"Term2")`